# ODP.NET 32 bit on Win 7 64 bit and Win Server 2003 64 bit

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-server-2003, windows-7-x64, odp.net

I have a `.NET winforms` application which uses `ODP` for connection to oracle db. ODP installation is 32 bit i'm developing the aplication on a `Win 7 64 bit machine`. I'm setting the platform target as x86 on the development machine and it runs ok.
But when i tested the application on `Win Server 2003 64 bit machine` it gave the exception

```
The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand' threw an exception.                                            

UNHANDLED EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.Dispose(Boolean disposing) 
at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()

UNHANDLED EXCEPTION SOURCE: Oracle.DataAccess

UNHANDLED EXCEPTION INNER EXCEPTION: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand..cctor()

UNHANDLED EXCEPTION DATA: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

UNHANDLED EXCEPTION MESSAGE: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand' threw an exception.
```

And when i set the platform target to `Any CPU` on Windows 7 64 bit it gives the exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

ODP version on development machine(Win 7 64 bit) is `11.2.0` and on the test machine(Win Server 2003 64 bit) is also 11.2.0

What should i do to run the application on both machines? Any idea?

Comment: There is `ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\odp.net\bin\2.x` but there is no `ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\odp.net\bin\4` directorry under my ODP instalaltion.

Answer (score 0):

IMO There are a few options:

1. Compile for x86 and install the 32 bit Oracle Client on your 64bit server (could run side by side if you change the ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN, ... system variables);
2. Compile for x86 and pack all DLL's for a 32 bit [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html) together with your binaries (make sure the TNS_ADMIN system variable is set otherwise you won't be able to use LDAP or tnsnames);
3. Compile your application for Any CPU but create a different set of dll's for x64 and x86 bit (Oracle.DataAcess.dll is compiled for a specific architecture, there is a version for x64 and one for x86);
4. Oracle is working on [a managed Oracle driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html), no Oracle client is required anymore, most codebases can converted easily but be aware that it's not feature complete yet and only supports Oracle 11+ databases.

Comment: For the most part I agree.  #1 does NOT require any changes to oracle_home or tns_admin - the newer versions of the provider first use the registry to locate unmanaged dlls.  Second - #3 - simply installing the 64 bit version on the dev machine should be enough.  From there you would NOT copy the Oracle.DataAccess.dll from machine to machine and instead rely on what is registered in the GAC.